# RoR - Slim - If Tag - Adds semicolon to end of line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, slim-lang

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I find it a fascinating langue. But there are aspects that I do not well understand and am not having time to read a book. So any help would be appreciated.

Some basic information about the project:

- Rails 3.2
- Ruby 2.0
- on Slim
- Spree e-commerce framework

I am trying to write an if-block to display a block of HTML only if the current page is not the shopping bag page.

Here is my code:

```
  - if !current_page(cart_path)?
  a href="#{cart_path}"
    div#shopping-cart-container class="btn"
      i.icon-shopping-cart
      - link = link_to_cart "Cart"
      = strip_tags link
```

When I run the page, I get the following error:

```
/var/www/odesk/cn/redrose_project/src/app/views/shared/_header.html.slim:15: syntax error, unexpected ';'
; if current_page(cart_path)?; 
                              ^
```

I think this is a Slim error. `current_page(cart_path)?` comes from the the documentation of the framework caz I am not still sophisticated to write my own logic.

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use "unless current_page(cart_path)?" instead of if not it is cleaner syntax

Comment: Thanks for the `unless`, sure looks neater... but I am having the same issue, `unexpected ';'`. Looks like Slim is appending a `;` after `?`

Comment: looks like you are using haml. are you indentions correct?

Comment: I am using Slim, which seems to be faster than Haml. Ok, this is what happened, I removed the `?`. Then it removed the `;` error. Now its some thing manageable. The function is not defined. Looks like I will have to write some logic. Thanks for the help @iRichLau . I will figure out if we need to use the `?` in Slim and submit an answer if no one has done so.